# How to use Rcpp in Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: c++, codeblocks, rcpp

I am trying to use **Rcpp** package in Code::Blocks IDE but when I try to compile a script with `#include<Rcpp.h>` I get an error saying that the file or repository does not exists.

I have the library **Rcpp** installed, so in **RStudio** I can run .cpp files.

The thing is I want to use **Rcpp** classes in a c++ script in Code::Blocks IDE.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the build of your IDE so that you can:

- access headers from R and Rcpp
- link against librairies from R and Rcpp

You may use `sourceCpp( , verbose = TRUE)` to have some examples:

For example, when `sourceCpp` this file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int zero(){
  return 0 ;
}
```

on my machine, I get this:

```
// ... lots of stuff irrelevant here ...
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/romain/Desktop" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -O3 -c test.cpp -o test.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o sourceCpp_28.so test.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

You can get some of these from `R CMD config` i.e.

```
$ R CMD config DYLIB_LDFLAGS
-dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -fopenmp
```

Comment: I tried to exactly reproduce what you did in your post, but I got different results, running the same file `test.cpp` and using `sourceCpp`on it I get this: <br/> `g++  -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/drodriguez/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/drodriguez"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c test.cpp -o test.o` <br/>  `g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_4.so test.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR`

Comment: Also I run `R CMD config DYLIB_LDFLAGS` on my console and I got this:  `-shared -fopenmp`  This is pretty different from what you got and I'm a little bit lost. pd: sorry for the comment appearence, but I am not familiar with this formatting.

Comment: It might be useful that you share these new results. Maybe someone will find a way to help you.

Comment: I would not worry about things like `DYLIB_LDFLAGS` being different. You're just on a different platform.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I see you are using `clang++` compiler while I am using `g++` compiler, maybe that's the difference.

Comment: I don't think so. It should work if you use the compiler you get with `R CMD config CXX`

Answer (score 0):

After a long search on the internet and ask for help from the c ++ programmers of the company where I am a fellow, I managed to find a viable solution to my problem, I will explain it next in case it is useful to somebody:

The solution is pretty simple, instead of trying to compile and execute an independent script, the key is to make a project in Code::Blocks and declare the script inside. After that just declare the Rcpp and R libraries inside the project, in file dependences, as also the dynamic libraries. This makes it possible to run `#include<Rcpp.h>` and so work with all the adventages it provides to R programmers.